# else part is not working whereas condition is false in php

Tags: php, forms

why the else part is not working? whereas condition is false. here is the code. please suggest:

```
function SignUp() { 
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) { 
        NewUser();} 
    else{ 
        echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";} 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: `if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) { ` since it is returning `false` by putting `!` you are making it true so you else condition is not working

Comment: Use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check whether the record already exists in the table or not.

Comment: And don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Please point out what the problem is when condition is false.

Comment: after removing ! it returns Duplicate entry for key primary.

Comment: use of mysql_num_rows() display blank screen.

Comment: when condition is wrong a blank screen appears instead of message user already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition and use `mysql_num_rows()` as:

```
function SignUp() { 

    if(isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        $query = mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM register WHERE 
            email = '$_POST[email]' 
            AND password = '$_POST[password]'
            ") or die(mysql_error()); 

        // if record exist
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
            echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
        }
        else{
            NewUser(); // register new user
        } 
    } 
}
```

---

**From your comments:**

*> use of mysql_num_rows() display blank screen. – Anks*

Add `error_reporting()` at top in your file and check what errors are you getting.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_`* or `PDO` extension because `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in PHP 7.

**[Mysqli Query PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)**

Comment: @Anks: what my friend??

Comment: @Anks: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php .. but before this, please solve your issue and than move on mysqli

Comment: @Anks: glad to help u

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrote some wrong syntax. Please replace code with below code.

```
function SignUp() { 
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."' AND password = '".$_POST['password']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) { 
        NewUser();
    } 
    else{ 
        echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";

    } 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: now only blank screen appears in the condition if user already exist in the database

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:- In developement mode, You should ON your [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in newer versions of PHP. So use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Write below lines in top of your php file to see all errors, warnings and notices.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Rewrite your function as below:-

```
function SignUp() { 
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());
        // $query returns true or false
        if($query) { 
            NewUser();
        } 
        else{ 
            echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
        } 
    } 
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: how to use mysql_i and PDO

Comment: This link will help you. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059